# R: gmp: inaccurate output from mod.bigz

Tags: r, gmp, largenumber, modulo

I downloaded the gmp package in order to calculate the modular exponentiation of very large numbers. But one of its functions, `mod.bigz`, seems to fail beyond a certain number of digits. For example, the answer to 100...00 mod 3 should be 1 since 99...99 is divisible by 3. But the answer I get is sometimes 0 or 2. Is there any way to fix this or is gmp just not accurate for very large numbers?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html

```
#install.packages('gmp')
library(gmp)
mod.bigz(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,3)
# 2
mod.bigz(10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,3)
# 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my overall advice is avoid falling back to base R at any point when you have those numbers in your code. If you fall back on regular R (or "regular most any programming language") at some point then it breaks.

For the original example you could wrap the inner number in `pow.bigz`:

```
mod.bigz(pow.bigz(10,50), 3)
# 1
mod.bigz(pow.bigz(10,55),3)
# 1
```

For the more complicated example we discussed in the comments, i.e. 693487563928456923569873549873658638579865348726988458, we get to the *real* solution which is to avoid falling back on R for the number via the `character` class:

```
mod.bigz("693487563928456923569873549873658638579865348726988458",3) # should be 0
# 0
mod.bigz("100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",3) # should be 1
# 1
```

Comment: This does work for the toy example. But I don't think it's the solution I'm looking for since I can't easily express a number with random digits as a^b, say for example, 693487563928456923569873549873658638579865348726988458. `mod.bigz` would then get the answer to mod 3 wrong -- it should be 0 since the sum of all digits is 321, a multiple of 3.
`mod.bigz(693487563928456923569873549873658638579865348726988458,3)`
`sum(as.integer(unlist(strsplit('693487563928456923569873549873658638579865348726988458',''))))`

Comment: @dasf Found the solution!! It's so easy haha. Just give me 1 minute to update.